# angular2 click event of parent send child as target

Tags: angular

this click event:

```ts
  <tr  class="testte"  *ngFor="let objQer of QueriesDetailsTtoalArray;let i = index;" [attr.dataQ]="objQer.text" (click)="chnageS(inptSQLq,$event)">
```

clicking on the row and the target is

```ts
<td>some text</td>
```

I do I send the tr when clicking on it and not the child element?

Another thing is that angular2 take dataQ attribute and change it to dataq,I just thought to myself, is this a normal behavior of a framework Being so obsessed with the doom ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a template variable you can reference the element and pass it to the event handler:

```ts
 <tr  class="testte"  *ngFor="let objQer of QueriesDetailsTtoalArray;let i = index;" 
    [attr.dataQ]="objQer.text" 
    #self
    (click)="chnageS(inptSQLq,$event, self)">
```